# ASP.net web hosting to IIS not accessible over intranet

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-hosting

I am hosting a ASP.NET application with in intranet with URL. When i host it without a specific URL it works and accessible over the intranet with my IP/computer name.

[image: Hosting to IIS]

[image]

[image]

But When i try to give it some specific URL it's not accessible. Following are the images for my IIS settings 
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your IIS only accepts incoming site requests for this specific URL. So what you need to do is to establish a DNS server within your intranet which tells the client to which IP to connect. The request of the client now contains the URL name and the IIS will accept the connection.

So your task will be:

- Install DNS server which maps your domain name to the server's ip

Comment: If you are unable to install a DNS server and have just a few computers in the network, you can manually change the `hosts` files for each machine (located in `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc`)